# C# interaction with browser for simple check

Tags: javascript, c#

Alright so I got a big project which I will start from the beginning. I've only done PHP and other web languages (Javascript, Jquery, node) and I have no experience with any of the languages mentioned above.

What I need to achieve is to have a small program written in C# that will make a call to my website, and the website will simply give me an "Okay" if it did recieve the message.

This simply makes the browser checks if a certain local program is running or not.
Where would I need to start to achieve such thing?

Comment: The 2nd paragraph describes a typical web service that is being called but the 3rd paragraph would be more like a web program calling a normal program?  Can you detail more? (best is always with some code examples as to what is meant). Also the communicatoin between browser application and normal application can be done via a few different protocols like json,..... . And most of the time there are some requirements or protocols not wanted.

Comment: You want to check to see if a certain local program is running on the webserver, or check if a local program is running on the client's box and then inform the web server?

Comment: I want my browser to check if a certain local program is running. If the program is running I simply want to show "Ok" on the browser.